# How to detect borwser in jQuery 1.11?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any easy way how to detect browser and its version in jQuery 1.11?

There is deprecated $.browser. But I didn't find easy alternative for that in newer $.

Comment: You don't really want to do that.

Comment: You don't. You detect for the features you're wanting to support, not for the browser itself.

Comment: it was removed because browser detection is not a good idea.... instead you do feature detection

Comment: You usually don't want to check for browsers, but for supported features.

Comment: The universe implodes if you do browser sniffing. And kitties die. Each time.

Comment: you can use libraries like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to do it

Comment: you can still make use of $.browser if you use the jquery migrate plugin